# how do i authenticate the user and load a table view on success?

Tags: iphone

i'm new to iphone dev..  i was trying to create an application which will authenticate the user and download some data from de url(.php) via xml parsing into the table view. i have figured how to parse and populate the table view but stuck up with user authentication... ie- extracting textfield data and appending it to the URL on submit. n loading table view on success... could anyone please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m going to separate this answer into two parts: one for appending the user name onto the URL and another for populating the table view.

**Appending the User Name Onto the URL**
Right now, you probably have a string for the URL (we’ll call it `URLString`) and a text field for the username (we’ll call it `usernameTextField`). Here is how you would append the contents of the text field to the URL string.

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://your.domain.goes.here/something?user=";

NSString *userName = [ usernameTextField text ];

NSString *newURLString = [ URLString stringByAppendingString:userName ];

NSURL *URLToLoad = [ NSURL URLWithString:newURLString ];
```

That gives you an `NSURL` to use in fetching the data.

**Populating the Table View**
Here, you want to have a function that loads the data from the URL. Where you currently parse the XML, add in some error-checking that checks to see if the page is valid. If so, you can call

```
[ tableView reloadData ];
```

to reload the table view. In your table view data source’s implementation of the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `numberOfRowsInSection:`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and other methods, check to see if valid data has been received and, if not, either display no sections and no rows or display a cell with a message to the user to log in.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myTextField text];
```

this line will extract data from your text field. for login you can use NSMutableURLRequest ot, for rxample, ASIHTTPRequest(this is third-party library) to login. then you can show your tableView in request's delegate method